# array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

In the following code , in the echo of preview why i am getting only h.

```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($thumb);
  echo $thumb=$thumb['thumb']."<br/>";
  echo $preview=$thumb['preview'];
  exit;

Array
(
    [thumb] => http://dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net/4d52463406ce5.jpg
    [preview] => http://dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net/4d5246345dac0.jpg
)
http://dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net/4d52463406ce5.jpg
h
```

Please suggest 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've overwritten `$thumb` variable. Change to:

```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($thumb);
  echo $thumb['thumb']."<br/>";
  echo $thumb['preview'];
  exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are turning the array into a string here:

```
$thumb=$thumb['thumb']
```

Comment: @zerkms but yours is more detailed... It'll win in the end :)

Comment: [irony mode on]AT SO IT IS MORE IMPORTANT TO GET MORE REP POINTS, AND NOT TO WRITE A BETTER ANSWER[/irony mode on] ;-)

Comment: @zerkms sweet, sweet reputation. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_rUyDhdZLna8/TQ5XESQnqaI/AAAAAAAAdLo/d5UnmxuLFxw/s400/scrooge-mcduck-christmas.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It´s because of this line:

```
echo $thumb=$thumb['thumb']."<br/>";
```

Remove the `$thumb=`